# How could I Implement inductive graph in haskell?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, graph, functional-programming

Given a graph described by the list of its edges, such as

```
[("c","cac"),("cac","cb"),("cac","bcc"),("c","ba")]
```

where `cac` comes after `c`, `cb` comes after `cac`, `bcc` comes after `cac` …

How do I convert it to a graph in the sense of [the fgl library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl-5.5.2.3/docs/Data-Graph-Inductive-Graph.html), so that I can make use of the graph algorithms therein?

Comment: You're already representing the graph as an edge list. Are you saying you want a different representation? Which one?

Comment: I was checking the below article but i get confused how to create it using mkGraph https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl-5.5.2.3/docs/Data-Graph-Inductive-Graph.html

Answer (score 3):

In `fgl`, nodes are identified by `Int`s. But the module [`Data.Graph.Inductive.NodeMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl-5.5.2.3/docs/Data-Graph-Inductive-NodeMap.html) can help you manage the mapping from your node names (`String`) to fgl’s nodes.

In particular, you can use `insMapNodes` on the list of strings in your list to create a `NodeMap`, and then pass that `NodeMap` and your list to `insMapEdges`.